# Academic Mailing List Quantitative Finance / Machine Learning

Tags: research, papers

I'm an early-stage researcher in Machine Learning for Finance. I was wondering if there are mailing lists where people post calls for papers, summer schools, conferences, open positions, and so on. For example, I've just found https://dbworld.sigmod.org/browse.html, which deals with Deep Learning topics. If you know something in the field of Quantitative Finance, Machine Learning, or similar, can you share it?

Comment: [SSRN](https://www.ssrn.com) posts call for papers, open positions, conferences, etc.

Comment: @amdopt, anything in particular on SSRN?

Comment: @RichardHardy I have an account and a subscription to the Financial Economics Network within SSRN. I get emails periodically that call attention to specific papers and events I have expressed interest in. The emails also include calls for papers, conferences, and open positions. I'm sure you can find the info without getting emails, but that's how I know of it.

Comment: @amdopt, got you. I subscribe to the same newsletter. It does not include much of machine learning, though.